# JAX-WS Web Services Without Java EE Containers 1.6 and 1.7

Tags: java, jax-ws, com.sun.net.httpserver

I was trying this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=lr7FO3rr8jg) in java 1.7, but if i selected java 1.6 i got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: runtime modeler error: Wrapper class com.company.jaxws.stockquote.service.jaxws.GetQuote is not found. Have you run APT to generate them?
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getClass(RuntimeModeler.java:256)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:567)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:514)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:341)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:227)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:308)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:174)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:420)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:439)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(EndpointImpl.java:208)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:138)
at com.company.jaxws.stockquote.service.StockQuoteService.publish(StockQuoteService.java:49)
at com.company.jaxws.stockquote.service.StockQuoteService.main(StockQuoteService.java:81)
Java Result: 1
```

the source is avaible [here](http://today.java.net/today/2007/07/03/ws_endpoint.zip)

All suggestions welcome.

Comment: Please include relevant information in the question instead of pointing to external videos and articles.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to add  @SOAPBinding to your server endpoint implementation class.it may resolve the problem.


@WebService(name = "StockQuote", serviceName = "StockQuoteService")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT, use=Use.LITERAL)
public class StockQuoteImpl {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getQuote")
    public double getQuote(String ticker) {
        double result = 0.0;
        if (ticker.equals("MHP")) {
            result = 50.0;
        } else if (ticker.equals("IBM")) {
            result = 83.0;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```